# listing mysql values in android with php

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

So far i can only get responses to show for example like:

```
echo 111;
```

I'm using this code to parse the responses:

```
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code",
            getString(R.string.code)));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", szid));
    // String valid = "1";
    String response = null;
    try {
        checkback.setText("Checking Version...");
        response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(
                "http://synamegames.com/giveaway/versioncheckid.php",
                postParameters);
        String res = response.toString();
        // res = res.trim();
        res = res.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

Is there any way I can list out 5 other values and have android arrange them to be in order like this?

```
ID | Code
1  | 512
2  | 521
3  | 232
4  | 315
5  | 124
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the same tutorial, now working on [**this one**](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/) to get a list view from MySQL results.